# Using Script# with SharePoint 2010

Tags: script#

Has anybody managed to successfully use Script# v 0.7.3 along with SharePoint 2010?
From my experience it breaks standard SharePoint functionality (like adding a web part to webpart page) after referencing mscorelib.js from the page (and God knows what else).
So it seems Script# js runtime conflicts with MS Ajax 3.5 library (that comes with SharePoint 2010) somehow.
I know that Nikhil has decided not to support MS Ajax anymore as a runtime for Script#. But what if I **have to use Script# alongside with MS Ajax**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newest version of script# 0.8 (not yet released, but what you get if you build from the repository at https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp) has big changes that should help here.

First script# no longer extends any built-in script objects - neither methods on built-in types, nor on their prototypes. I suspect Sharepoint used to be broken because of Array prototype extensions (why does sharepoint use arrays like dictionaries!?) but anyway, that should no longer happen.

Furthermore, by default (i.e. you have to do a bit of customization if you want to turn it off), script# generates to the AMD pattern. That implies everything in script# is scoped into a module (named 'ss'), and only dependent modules get a reference to it (by declaring their dependency). This further reduces conflict, and in worse cases, actually would allow multiple versions to co-exist.

Hope that will help...

Comment: Thank you, Nikhil! VERY glad to hear that! Now I feel absolutely armed  to struggle with such a beast as SharePoint client side development.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use MS Ajax you shouldn't use mscorlib. The version compatible with Ajax is aacorlib. It is a workable solution but you will not have all the funcionalities that you have in mscorlib.
I found very useful to read this pdf to get all the general knowledge about ScriptSharp:
http://projects.nikhilk.net/Content/Projects/ScriptSharp/ScriptSharp.pdf

It is for version 0.5.5.0 but all the main concepts are still valid. 
Hopefully there will be an updated version soon..

Comment: As a SharePoint 2010 developer I have to use MS Ajax 3.5 Library on the client and I'm not considering the situation when I get bound to the v 0.5.5.0 of Script# forever. For me it's ok to use the both: mscorelib.js and MS Ajax Library. But it seems they can't coexist together. So I can't use Script# v 0.7.3.0 with SharePoint 2010. Possibly I can't use it with Sharepoint 2007, Asp.Net 3.5 or 4.0 web sites that use MS Ajax library. If it's so, the question is: which real world scenarios I can use Script# 0.7.3.0 for? Has anyone successfully used Script# v 0.7.3.0 in scenarios described above?

Comment: Well, I've investigated this issue with inability to add a web part on the page with mscorlib.js added. It has turned out exactly the very same issue Nikhil K. pointed out [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843260/script-and-asp-net-updatepanels-compatibility). Namely, it happens because of mscorlib.js extends Array.prototype (but actually the main issue is how MS gyus iterating js arrays). Just google a phrase "Sharepoint Array prototype" to know more about it. So the only option left is to redesign Script# to avoid extending Array.prototype.