# Script# and Asp.Net updatepanels compatibility

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, script#

This is a simple question, NikhilK answered to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027665/new-version-of-script-0-6-and-asp-net-ajax-where-is-microsoftajaxext-js):
"Script# doesn't support ASP.NET Ajax anymore"

Does that mean that we can't use Asp.net UpdatePanels (which need a ScriptManager) in the same page where we load mscorlib.js? Even if mscorlib is manipulating DOM elements that are not inside the updatepanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I mentioned asp.net ajax is not supported, it is primarily a two-fold statement:

1. MSAjax assemblies allowing you to program against the msajax scripts are no longer included.
2. There was a mode of the compiler which caused generated script to use the type system defined in msajax scripts.

Conceptually you should be able to load mscorlib.js and program using it in any page, including one using asp.net ajax (and update panels). As a heads-up you may run into one particular issue... mscorlib.js extends Array.prototype, which I don't think affects msajax scripts, but might affect some other scripts (eg. sharepoint scripts).

In the future, I plan to generate scripts differently that would not require extending Array.prototype, but that work hasn't been done yet.

So hopefully that clarifies things. If you try and run into issues, I'd love to know. I can't guarantee they'll be fixed (esp. given that even asp.net is primarily focused around jQuery rather then the old msajax scripts), but I can try helping to see if any of them have reasonable workarounds.